# Request-reply between 2 systems using ApacheCamel

Tags: apache-camel, eip

I am very new to EIP and ApacheCamel and need some help from the experts. 
The question is basically about the best way to retrieve data from system B that system A requires using ApacheCamel. 
For example:
System B has MultiplyService. 
System A needs to use that Service via ApacheCamel. 
ApacheCamel receives the request from System A, pass it to system B (somehow), wait for the response then pass it back to system A.
So far the example I found online assumes the MultiplyService lives in ApacheCamel itself:

`from("jms:queue:numbers").to("multiplier");`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no best way but most suitable way. You must decide kind of endpoint(generic or specific) that you want to use. Within same camel context - direct, seda. Within same jvm - vm. Within same network - jms, http, tcp. There are a lot of possibilities. So, please give more specific requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply hutingung, here are my answers: endpoint => generic (other systems can use it via ApacheCamel). Same Camel Context - direct. Not necessarily same JVM. Within same network - JMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a lot of options, in general I would wrap any services that need to be exposed to other applications with HTTP (jetty), REST (cxfrs), SOAP (cxfws) or JMS (AMQ request/reply)...

define this in system B...

```
from("jetty://localhost:9001/multiplier).process(new MyMultiplierService());
```

and invoke it from system A like this...

```
from("jms:queue:numbers").to("jetty://localhost:9001/multiplier");
```

Comment: Thanks boday, I was thinking of wrapping the service with JMS/REST and create a processor in Camel that connects to it (System B). I am not sure about your suggestion "**define this in system B**" would work as System B doesn't use Camel.

Comment: how does System B expose the MultiplyService?

Comment: Thanks boday.. I've done more reading and now I understand how it works little bit better. **Polling Consumer** can be used with your example above.